# About using namespace std in C++

Tags: c++

If we use

> using namespace std

in our source file, in which step is the definition of namespace imported to our source file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the namespace is imported when you write:

```
#include <iostream>
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

by writing `using namespace std` you don't import the namespace, you allow using its entities without `std` prefix, like `cout` instead of `std::cout`